# I am creating an application that uses Net Beans / JavaFx / Scene builder. The app will contain 8 scenes one contains graphics

Tags: javafx

My process would be to create a method that will draw a line from a start position (x,y) to an end position (x,y) on a Image view background. The only code I have been able to see creates a single stage including the main etc. This does not work in the current structure using a controller. Is there a way to create a method in a controller that will perform this task? The code exists to put an image on the scene in a controller method and draw lines based on coordinates but I see no way to combine the two features.

Comment: This question needs clarity. If you have found a working pure code example and are having a hard time making that code work in a `Controller`, I suggest you spend some time doing tutorials related to FXML.

Comment: When asking questions, I also advise making the title of your question an actual question,  e.g. "How to use a JavaFX controller to draw a line?", then include in the body of the question a [mcve] of your attempt to answer it.  You will likely have a better chance of getting your question answered if you do that.